# Does norcamphor have enantiomers?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, chirality

The following two molecular structures have two chiral centers, so in total four chiral centers:

[image: bicyclo[2.2.1]heptan‐2‐one]

I did the absolute configuration multiple times and I keep getting *R*,*R* and *S*,*S*, which should be enantiomers. My book says these two are “*identical molecules that are superimposable*”. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: These two are enantiomers.

Comment: Just try superimposing these two structures! BTW your CIP assignments are incorrect. Assignments to bicyclic compounds are not straightforward. Reading left to right, they are (1S,4R)-bicyclo[2.2.1]heptan-2-one and (1R,4S)-bicyclo[2.2.1]heptan-2-one. (Take a look at the case of camphor [here](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/isomers/RS14272/pinene.html#camphor). (Don’t be confused by the R,R assignment to camphor.)